# Run rails app under subfolder

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, deployment, routes

I've been testing my rails app on localhost:3000 and it works just fine. However, when deploying to my host, the root URL is:

http://99.88.77.66/~username

I do not have a domain name at this point.

When I point the browser to the above URL I get the root not found for:

/~username

Alternatively for

http://99.88.77.66/~username/controller/index

I get this route not found:

/~username/controller/index

I'm using Rials 4.2.3 and Ruby 2.0.

How can I make my routes work with this kind of subfolder until I can get an appropriate domain name?

Comment: Which is the server you are using?

Comment: I'm on apache and passenger on a shared server at Site5

Comment: @user2666194 /~username is your root url or your root directory ??

Comment: That's the root URL. The root directory is /home/username/railsappname

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `config.relative_url_root` in `config/environments/production.rb`:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#deploy-to-a-subdirectory-relative-url-root

Comment: For passenger, you also need to add: PassengerBaseURI /~subfoldername in your .htaccess file.